# How does the piercing modifier affect a Laser Glaive?

Tags: dead-cells

I found a Laser Glaive with the the modifier "Shots pierce the first target". The Laser Glaive's description says "bounces on nearby targets", which in practice means it will bounce back and forth between enemies if any are nearby.

How does the piercing modifier work on Laser Glaive? Is there any benefit when the weapon already bounces between enemies?

[image: Laser Glaive with piercing]

Comment: I'm wondering if pierce could allow the Glavie to hit shielded enemies.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar post on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/deadcells/comments/yqhl4h/bug_the_laser_glaive_can_bet_pierce_prefix_but_it/) asking if it's a bug:

[image]

Comment: The glaive will bounce forwards without the pierce.

Comment: Ok then it's not supposed to have that feature, so it's likely a bug